# How to install FFTW library on Eclipse CDT (Windows) correctly?

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll, eclipse-cdt, fftw

I installed FFTW library by the following step , but i'm not sure if i do it correctly.

> 1.download the precompiled .dll from [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html/%22FFTW%22)
>
> 2.put fftw3.h into include , and add libfftw3-3.dll to MinGW C++ Linker/library

And then i tested the code below(copy from [here](https://youtu.be/CMyG4hsKCJo?t=5m8s/%22here%22)).

But i found that **fftw_plan_dft_1d()** function will cause my program not able to startup like...

***ERROR :*** (Suspended) During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

Please help my find out what i missed .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 0


int main() {

    const int n=5;
    fftw_complex x[n];
    fftw_complex y[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        x[i][REAL] = i+1;
        x[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }

    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n,x,y,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();

    cout<<"FFT = "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        if(y[i][IMAG]<0)
            cout<<y[i][REAL] << " - " <<abs(y[i][IMAG]) <<"i"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<y[i][REAL] << " + " <<y[i][IMAG] <<"i"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to copy `libfftw3-3.dll` into directory where your executable will be able to find it at startup. Probably into build directory, such as "Debug" or "Release" .

Comment: But there is no build error show up when i build project. And there were errors before i add .dll into linker library.

Comment: If you link dll to executable you also need to make sure executable will be able to find this dll at runtime.

Comment: Yes , you're right! Problem solved! Thank you!